# Не доставляются на почту кириллические значения полей selecta - почему?

Tags: php, html, select, sendmail

Есть форма для отправки заявки в которой содержится `select` с выбором опций.

Само письмо доходит на ящик нормально и значение `value` лациницей тоже, только вот вот вместо значений в кирриллице - обозначение вида **A5**.

Как доставлять кириллические значения полей?

```
<form name="sentMessage" method="POST" action="contact.php">
...
<select name="theme">
    <option value="тематика не выбрана">Выберите тематику</option>
    <option value="здоровье">здоровье</option>
    <option value="карьера">карьера</option>
    <option value="культура">культура</option>
    <option value="музыка">музыка</option>
    <option value="наука">наука</option>
    <option value="teach">обучение</option>
</select>
</form>
```

И есть файл **contact.php** следующего содержания

```
<?php 
    $to = "Email"; /*Your Email*/
    $subject = "Issue"; /*Issue*/
    $msg="Theme: $_POST[theme]";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"."From: $_POST[email]";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

UPD: дополнил кодировкой в хэдере - на яндекс ящике теперь отображается все верно, но решение не универсально - к примеру, во [временном ящике](https://temp-mail.org) выводятся кракозябры.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте кодировку, которую указываете в хэдере и оберните все аутпуты в urlencode - возможно поможет избежать проблем.
Да и вообще, желательно в форме указывать все value хотя бы транслитом, а не русскими буквами.

Comment: Понятно, что можно транслитом, но что получается я хочу именно кириллицу указать и допустим пользователю в таком виде передать - я это сделать не могу? только транслитом? да нуу, бред какой-то. С кодировкой определенные проблемы есть, но вот такой заголовок ситуацию не спасает
`$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"."From: $_POST[email]";` как и `urlrencode` тоже...

Comment: Хотя, это вероятно проблема самого интерпретатора почты. В яндекс почте все нормально прочитало..